# Why for discrete valuation fields $K\subset L$ it holds that $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

This must be an easy question, but I am confused. We are given a complete discrete valuation field $K$ and its finite extension $L$.

I knew that in this setting it is true that $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$. My argument was that $\mathcal O_K$ consists of all elements of $K$ with valuation $\geq 0$ and $\mathcal O_L$ consists of all elements of $L$ with valuation $\geq 0,$ thus, any element of $\mathcal O_K$ being an element of $K\subset L$ and having valuation $\geq 0$ must lie inside $\mathcal O_L$. However, during this argument I imagined that valuation $\nu_L$ on $L$ is simply the unique continuation of valuation $\nu_K$ on $K$. Now I have huge doubts about that.

On the other hand, there is this notion of ramification index $e$, telling us that $\nu_K=\frac{1}{e} \nu_L.$ Hence, my assumption about $\nu_K$ and $\nu_L$ was wrong, so there must be other reason why $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$ and $\mathfrak{m}_K\subset \mathfrak{m}_L$. Of course, if $\nu_K(x)\geq 0$ then $\nu_L(x) \geq 0$ and previous argument still works, but for us even introducing ramification index and stating that $\nu_K=\frac{1}{e} \nu_L$ we at first must be sure that $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$. So, what is the explanation for this inclusion?

Thank you.

Comment: The crux of the matter is that $L$ is a complete discrete valuation field, which is a non-trivial fact. The right way to clear your doubts depends on the order in which you're proving and defining things, which I do not know. The way I learned this subject, one first lets $A$ be the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $L$ (that clearly contains $\mathcal{O}_K$), then proves that $A$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module of rank $[L\colon K]$ and then use this to prove that $A$ is a complete DVR whose intrinsic topology agrees with the module topology.

Comment: This makes $L$ into a complete discrete valuation field with $\mathcal{O}_L=A$ and the formula $\nu_K=\frac{1}{e}\nu_L$ only enters the picture afterwards.

Comment: I am familiar with the fact that $\mathcal O_L$ is free $\mathcal O_K$-module of dimension $[L:K].$ However, I don't get why this knowledge would be sufficient to know that $\nu_K=\frac{1}{e}\nu_L$. The way I am learning this stuff is that this formula enters the picture as one of equivalent definitions of ramification index. We first learn that $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$ and $\mathfrak{m}_K\subset \mathfrak{m}_L$, then say that $\pi_K \mathcal O_L$ is an ideal in $\mathcal O_L$, thus is of form $(\pi_K^e)$ and then we deduce the formula. Are you saying that it can be deduced faster?

Comment: No, I'm not. I would deduce it the same way you're suggesting. Really, the formula is not relevant here.

Comment: Oh, ok. I kinda hoped that $\mathcal O_K \subset \mathcal O_L$ could be deduced on the level of definitions, without considering $\mathcal O_L$ as integral closure of $\mathcal O_K$ in $L.$ Anyway, thank you!

Comment: The thing is that for $\mathcal{O}_L$ to even make sense in the first place, you have to know that $L$ is a complete discrete valuation field. This is a non-trivial fact and, in proving it, you automatically obtain that $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq\mathcal{O}_L$ post hoc.